# Setting Up Reverse DNS

Tags: domain-name-system, vps, reverse-dns

I am on a VPS with root access.

Using WHM I followed the instructions [here](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/WHMDocs/RdnsForBind)

```
I put the last octet in my ip address in the domain field.
left the TTL as 14400.
Set the record type to PTR
In the hostname field I put websitename.com
```

this resulted in a `.in-addr.arpa not found: 2(SERVFAIL)` when doing hosts in the command line

I then put the following in my resolv.conf

```
search websitename.com
nameserver xx.xxx.xxx.xx (with the right ip address instead of the x's)
nameserver xx.xxx.xxx.xx

which resulted in xx.xxx.xxx.xx.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer websitename.com.
```

checks on dnsstuff.com still say there is no reverse DNS record, however I think when it updates in 24hrs it will then say it is there.

but I just want to double check that I have done this correctly before I leave it 24hrs.

Answer (score 4):

Unless you own the netblock you can't set the reverse DNS for non RFC1918 addresses. You need to have the owner of the netblock setup the correct reverse entries for you (your VPS provider) or delegate control to you (if you are using just a single VPS more hassle than it's worth, and they probably wouldn't do it anyway).

Comment: yeh just a single VPS

Comment: Zypher's is the correct answer. Unless the netblock your IP is in has been delegated to you (which is beyond unlikely), you can't handle reverse DNS for it. You can see the nameserver that's authoritative using `dig` like so: `dig +trace -x a.b.c.d` where a.b.c.d is your IP.

Comment: @James yeah contact whoever does your webhosting with the IP and DNS record in hand.